# How to denormalize data

Tags: sas

I have a proc means output that has rows for each summary statistics and columns for each variable. How can I "pivot" this so it is unique by the "by" variable?

My workaround is to take the output and merge it onto itself using WHERE and RENAME commands. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
proc means data=data1 n mean max min std noprint;
  var var1 var2;
  by month;
  output out=SummaryStats;
run;
data SummaryStatsUnique;
  merge SummaryStats (in=in1 keep=month var1 var2 _stat_ rename=(var1=var1_N var2=var2_N) where=(_stat_="N"))
        SummaryStats (in=in2 keep=month var1 var2 _stat_ rename=(var1=var1_MEAN var2=var2_MEAN) where=(_stat_="MEAN"))
        SummaryStats (in=in3 keep=month var1 var2 _stat_ rename=(var1=var1_MAX var2=var2_MAX) where=(_stat_="MAX"))
        SummaryStats (in=in4 keep=month var1 var2 _stat_ rename=(var1=var1_MIN var2=var2_MIN) where=(_stat_="MIN"))
        SummaryStats (in=in5 keep=month var1 var2 _stat_ rename=(var1=var1_STD var2=var2_STD) where=(_stat_="STD"))
  ;
  by month;
  if ^(first.month and last.month) then abort;
  if ^(in1 and in2 and in3 and in4 and in5) then abort;
run;
```

This should take a table formatted like this:

```
MONTH     _STAT_     Var1     Var2
2019.01   N          19       15
2019.01   MEAN       17.5     13
2019.01   MAX        21       16
2019.01   MIN        15       12
2019.01   STD        2.5      1.5
2019.02   ...
```

and output like this:

```
MONTH     VAR1_N     VAR2_N     VAR1_MEAN    VAR2_MEAN   ...
2019.01   19         15         17.5         13
2019.02   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the PROC MEANS/SUMMARY default output data set to auto name style.

```
proc means noprint missing chartype data=sashelp.class;
   class sex;
   output out=stat1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=stat1(drop=_freq_) out=stat2;
   by _type_ sex _stat_ notsorted;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=stat2 out=stat3 delim=_;
   by _type_ sex;
   id  _name_ _stat_;
   var col1;
   run; 
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use AUTONAME and create the data directly.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.class nway;
   class age;
   var height weight;
   output out=summary n= mean= max= min= std= / autoname;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just curious if this wasn't from a proc summary and I wanted to get the data table to get from the starting table to the ending table is there any good way to do that with a SAS procedure? For instance if the _STAT_ column was some other classification column and it was unique by MONTH and this new column. The only way I can think of is to do what is in my original code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NathanPrzybylo Sure see my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think these options give you a more useful data set with variables in rows with CLASS levels.

```
ods select none;
proc means data=sashelp.class n mean max min std stackods;
   class age;
   var height weight;
   ods output summary=summary;
   run;
ods select all;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]